# UIWebView doesn't appear in DetailViewController when called from a button inside a Popover

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, master-detail

I have an iOS project with the following files inside it:

```
**PopOverContentViewController.h, 
PopOverContentViewController.m, 
MasterViewController.h, 
MasterViewController.m, 
DetailViewController.h, 
DetailViewController.m.**
```

I created some buttons in PopOverViewController which have this method as their action:

```
- (void) buttonPressed
{
    NSLog(@"The button was pressed");
    UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc]
    initWithFrame:self.detailViewController.view.bounds]; 
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lau.edu.lb"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
    [myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
    [self.detailViewController.view addSubview:myWebView];
    if ([self isInPopover])
    {
        [self.myPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not seeing the webpage opening, the DetailviewController doesn't change.
Keep in mind I have the following lines written in PopOverContentViewController.h:

```
@class DetailViewController;
@property DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

And that I have imported DetailViewController.h to the implementation file of PopOverViewController.

I tried loading a page from information in the masterviewcontroller and it appeared in the detailviewcontroller, but I'm clueless as to why it isn't working from the popover.

Thank you!